# TypeError: Variable in Object State is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm very new to react.js and i got a question about my program. I am getting a type error when i try to invoke a method when the corresponding buttton is clicked. Basically the method generates a random number and i want to display this number in another component. For this to work i have to write the return in the variable 'defNum' located in the object state. I hope you can help me :)

My Code in the **context.js**:

```
  defaultNumber = () => {
    let defNumChange = [...this.state.defNum];
    defNumChange = Math.random().toString(8).substr(2);
    defNumChange = parseInt(defNumChange);
    console.log(defNumChange);
    this.setState(() => {
  return {
    defNum: defNumChange,
  };
});
```

And this is my state object also located in the **context.js:**

```
  state = {
    products: [],
    detailProduct: detailProduct,
    cart: [],
    modalOpen: false,
    modalProduct: detailProduct,
    subTotal: 0,
    delivery: 0,
    totalSum: 0,
    defNum: 0,
  };
```

This is the **component** where i want to display my *return value* of the method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";

export default class thankYou extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <ProductConsumer>
    {(value) => {
      const { defNum } = value;
      return (

        <React-Fragement>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row mt-2 mb-2">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="jubotron text-center text-titel">

                  <p></p>
                  <h4>Vielen Dank für deine Bestellung!</h4>
                  <hr />
                  <p className="mt-6">
                    Wenn dir unsere Produkte gefallen komme gerne wieder auf
                    uns zurück
                  </p>

                  <p className="mt-6">
                    <strong>
                      Dein .Dog.Styles. Team freut sich auf dich
                    </strong>
                  </p>
                  <p className="mt-6">
                    Bitte überprüfe deine E-Mails, um weitere Details zu
                    erhalten.
                  </p>
                  <hr />
                  <p></p>

                  <p className="mt-6">
                    <strong>Deine Bestellnummer: {defNum} </strong>      <------ THIS ONE :)
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </React-Fragement>
      );
    }}
  </ProductConsumer>
);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `defnum` is integer as per your `state`(0) and its not iterable.It should either be an `array` or `Set`or `object` or string to be iterable.

```
let defNumChange = [...this.state.defNum]; // so this won't work
```

> Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or
> string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for
> function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected,or an
> object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more
> key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected

See doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

What you can do is ,add `double quotes` to the value (Just a hack) of `defnum`to make it iterable

```
 state = {
    products: [],
    detailProduct: detailProduct,
    cart: [],
    modalOpen: false,
    modalProduct: detailProduct,
    subTotal: 0,
    delivery: 0,
    totalSum: 0,
    defNum: "0", // as string is iterable this will work
  };
```

Comment: now it's working thank you so much! Definitely learned something new today :)